# inner_product of map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

can inner_product not be applied to a map.
I have the following code:

```
std::map<class A, class B> s;
std::map<class A, class B>::const_iterator vit=s.begin();
long double x = std::inner_product(vit->first,vit->second,vit->first,0.0);
```

but I get a no-matching function to inner_product error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly can be applied to maps, given creatively chosen functors, but `inner_product` expects iterators, while `vit->first` is a `const A` and `vit->second` is a `B`.

For example,

```
std::map<int, double> m = {{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}};
typedef std::map<int, double>::value_type val_t;
double x = std::inner_product(m.begin(), m.end(), m.begin(), 0.0,
           std::plus<double>(),
           [](val_t lhs, val_t rhs){return lhs.first * rhs.second;});
```

Comment: so, I should replace vit->first with vit and vit->second with an end iterator

Comment: these are the errors I am getting : 
test.h:60:141: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
test.h:60:141: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_function.h:135:12: error: provided for ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::plus’

Comment: @itcplpl well give it `-std=c++0x` as it is asking, or write a C++98-style functor. Test run: https://ideone.com/sedmF